# How to submit an app to AppStore for only specific people?

Tags: ios, app-store

So I am almost finished with my app. One version is for all users to download for an establishment. The other is an admin version of the app where the admin can install and make changes to his/her app (add photos, change menu etc.) and all changes are immediately visible to the original user version of the app.

Once the admin version is purchased by an establishment. I will submit the free user version to the app store.

However, I want the admin version to be available only to specific people. It doesn't make sense for anyone to download and install the admin version of the app (eventhough it's password protected).

I don't like to install the app to the establishment's phone directly because it would make the upgrades difficult.

Is there actually a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDM solution :

1. This will require users to enroll their devices to your MDM server , I don't think that an enterprise employees will register their devices to your MDM server and most chances that they already registered to their MDM server.
2. Using your enterprise account to distribute apps to other enterprises violates Apple enterprise account agreement!

Custom B2B solution:

1. With custom B2B solution you can use AppStore platform to distribute variations of your app to relevant enterprises.
2. The enterprises that want to purchase your app will have to be registered to the VPP (Volume Purchase Program).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why would the enterprises be registered to the VPP program? They would only be purchasing the 1 admin version of the app. However, the admin version app would be available to everybody. I guess if somebody purchased it just to try it out, they would be hugely disappointed as they could not be able to use the app. Would this create a problem for the app store? Would it be rejected because of this?

Comment: 1.An enterprise have to be registered to VPP because it's the only way they can get custom B2B app, and it's the only way you can distribute custom app to specific people using the AppStore, otherwise your app will have to be available to all AppStore user. 2.If you want to give some one a trial app then give it to them for free and charge for the none trial app, the VPP price can be free.

Comment: That means, if a company is registered to VPP then developers can target specific companies in the app store. This is exactly what I need. Unless of course there are harsh reqirements for registering as VPP. I will look into it. Thank you.

Comment: Yes , that's exactly right , but you have to contact them to get their agent's Apple ID because that's how you control who can get your custom B2B app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Enterprise account for that Admin app if you dont want it to be installable by others. Use one of the MDM tools available to manage updates and provisioning.

If your admin version is a digital purchase, you either put in on app store and pay the 30% cut or distribute with an enterprise account, use your own MDM process and keep all the money. (But, I'm not sure if Apple will approve an enterprise account if your goal is to circumvent the 30% cut)

Comment: Would Apple allow an app which was designed for a few people to use by design (such as an admin version of an app) to the app store?